# Returning integers from a text field

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

I need to return certain ID's from a text field in a SQL query. I am having difficulties joining to my temp table as the column I want to return data from that is holding the integers is actually a text field

I am running:

```
SELECT a.userID,a.name,a.list
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 tmp
ON a.list = tmp.skill
```

This returns:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 22
>   Operand type clash: text is incompatible with int

So, `tmp.skill` is the column that holds the duplicate IDs that I want to dig out in `a.list`. My `table2` has a list of 1300 IDs

Just to add to this, `a.list` from `table1` contains more than one ID. For example:

1234, 12345

So if 12345 appears in `tmp.skill` in `table2` then I want the list of users to return

Comment: Is there any trigger in your db, because your Statement has no line number 22

Comment: Your query cannot generate that error.  It has no function call in it, unless one of the tables is really a view.

Comment: Ignore the line number 22 @Jens ... I have written a query further up apologies that was not clear

Comment: @GordonLinoff - apologies I have updated the error now

Comment: Please dear god - JUST CHANGE YOUR DATA MODEL! You shouldn't put numbers in varchar columns, LET ALONE TEXT COLUMNS (which are deprecated anyway btw)

Comment: That was really helpful thanks @Milney

Comment: @Brett - That is actually helpful... if you change the data model to a sensible one, then you no longer have to solve this issue - Eg. problem is solved and my suggestion was 'helpful'. Arguably more helpful than any other answer to this question as it will prevent having to ask more questions in future on how to work around an insane data model

Comment: Save yourself and anyone else who has to work on the database in the future headaches and just fix the ****ing data types!

Comment: According to Microsoft: IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql

Comment: If that was something that was in my hands then I wouldn't have asked this question in the first place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you compare text field with int that thats why thrown this error you need to convert int to text then you can use any comparison. so 1st convert skill this way  CONVERT(varchar, tmp.skill) then you can use like operator

```
SELECT a.userID,a.name,a.list
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 tmp
ON a.list like '%'+CONVERT(varchar(10), tmp.skill)+'%'
```